# jQuery sortable on contenteditable items

Tags: jquery, html, contenteditable

If I do "jquery sortable" on a contenteditable items, the item would never be editable.

I should mention that in IE every thing works fine and i have this problem in FF 3.6.8

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#sortable').sortable();
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="sortable">
    <p contenteditable="true">test</p>
  </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a `p` tag inside a `span` tag - it's invalid HTML, and could cause problems

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps use a handle?

```
<div id="sortable">
    <div>
        <span class="handle">Perhaps some icon here</span>
        <p contenteditable="true">Editable text..</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span class="handle">Perhaps some icon here</span>
        <p contenteditable="true">Editable text..</p>
    </div>
</div>


$("#sortable").sortable({
    handle: 'span'
});
```

P.S. You shouldn't nest `<p>` tags inside `<span>'s` :)

Comment: but by using handle: 'span', the container is not sortable anymore!